# English translation of transcript for admission that can't be from university

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, transcript-of-records, translations

I attend a university in Italy, and they don't issue transcripts in English language. The university I am intending to apply for in USA ask for English translation coming from the same university and not through certified translators which I find bizzare.

The transcript is only for admission, and therefore it's not official, I can submit the final one once admitted and finished the program.

Now, I can easily translate the transcript and copy the stamp from the original Italian transcript and it's not a big deal. But, I fear they might contact the university to ask if they have provided the English translation as well, which they don't.

What do you think about this situaion?

Comment: @NateEldredge, that is probably a good answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contact the university where you are applying, explain the situation and ask what to do, or what documents you should provide instead.

My guess is that they will accept a certified translation. They might even be willing to accept your own informal translation, with a certified copy to follow later if you are admitted, but ask them.

If you do provide your own unofficial translation, make sure that it is clearly marked as your own.  **Do not** copy an official stamp, or in any way attempt to pass it off as official.  This would be considered fraud, even if your translation is perfectly accurate.  If detected, you could expect to be immediately rejected, regardless of how good your record is.  This can also happen retroactively if it's discovered after you are admitted - even years later, potentially leading to degree revocation.